# Splitting string with "+" r

Tags: r, split

I would like to convert this combination of variables into string, then split it by variable with "+".

For instance:

```
list = c('apple', 'dog', paste0('Day', 1:5), paste0('Name', 1:5))
```

The ideal outcome is

```
"apple + dog + Day1 + Day2 + ...."
```

Just in case someone is interested in the motivation: I am running a regression with different predictors, and I am fetching the column names and combine them into a typical regression expression like `lm (Y~ apple + dog + Day1)`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We need a `paste` with `collapse` to change the `vector` of elements to a single string

```
str1 <- paste(list, collapse= " + ")
```

---

Or with `str_c` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str1 <- str_c(list, collapse = " + ")
```

---

Once we had the `paste` output, use it in `lm`

```
lm(paste0("Y ~ ", str1), data = dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `paste` with `collapse` argument to add characters among elements of one or more vectors.

So the code

```
paste(c('apple', 'dog', paste0('Day', 1:5), paste0('Name', 1:5)), collapse = " + ")
```

will produce

```
"apple + dog + Day1 + Day2 + Day3 + Day4 + Day5 + Name1 + Name2 + Name3 + Name4 + Name5"
```

EDIT: The question was answered by @akrun while writing my response :-(